# AbstractTable.update() - more complex condition?

Tags: database, qore

From the [docs](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/class_sql_util_1_1_abstract_table.html#aece9b105e62b9418a9e21ea88bce520f):

> ```
> int SqlUtil::AbstractTable::update (
> hash  set,
> hash  cond,
> reference< string >   sql,
> hash  opt 
> )
> ```
>
> updates rows in the table matching an optional condition and returns
>   the count of rows updated; no transaction management is performed with
>   this method
>   Example:
>
> `int ucnt = table.update(("id": id), ("name": name));`

where `("name": name)` is a condition hash. Can the condition be more complex though? What if I had a list or a hash `names` and wanted to update all rows with a name that is in it? Is it possible to do it with one update statement or do I need to iterate through `names`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the where condition can be complex with [update statements generated by SqlUtil](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/sql_operations.html#updating_data).

The [where condition](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/sql_operations.html#where_clauses) is represented by the `cond` parameter in the method docs in your question.

To update rows based on a match from a list of values, use [`op_in()`](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/group__sql__op__funcs.html#ga238bdd76156f8375738227369543e444) as follows:

```
int rows = table.update(("col1": val1, "col2": val2), ("col3": op_in(my_list)));
```

This will generate SQL like:

```
update table set col1 = %v, col2 = %v where col3 in (%v)
```

(NOTE: the exact SQL generated will differ depending on the underlying database, and the `%v` characters are placeholder specifications for [bind by value operations](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/class_qore_1_1_s_q_l_1_1_datasource.html#sql_binding) in the generated SQL where the actual values are sent separately to the SQL server for reasons described in the previous link)

To update values based on a match of a another column value, use [`op_like()`](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/group__sql__op__funcs.html#ga8364df3f5e1c34c3e580b20560e9fbb4) as in:

```
int rows = table.update(("col1": val1, "col2": val2), ("col3": op_like("%some value%")));
```

Which will generate SQL like:

```
update table set col1 = %v, col2 = %v where col3 like %v
```

In general you can use any [SQL operator function](https://docs.qore.org/current/modules/SqlUtil/html/group__sql__op__funcs.html) in the where clause of the update method.